# Unable to load image from localhost url because of cross origin

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, cross-domain

I am trying to get image data uri through image url using the function below, however, I kept getting a cross origin error even though the image is stored in the localhost folder. Can anyone help me with this?

```
var img = new Image();
            img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            img.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var dataURL;
                canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
                canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
                var imageAttribute = {
                    dataUrl: dataURL,
                    height: canvas.height,
                    width: canvas.width
                };
                if (callback) callback(imageAttribute, options);
            };
            img.src = url;
            console.log(img.src);
```

The code throws cross origin issue on the line `img.src = url` as it tries to hit my localhost url.
Below is the error that is shown in the console.

`Access to image at 'https://localhost:44377//Data/files/logo-rs.png' from origin 'https://localhost:44376' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I found the answer - [possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: Your image URL has a different port number, and so is [considered to be from a different origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An origin is a domain, plus a scheme and port number.

you use two different port 44376 and 44377

44376 only access to 44377 when on the header of 44377 response was something like this

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:44376**

and how to add this header to your responses, it depends on your server

you can see Apache, IIS6, IIS7, PHP and ASP.NET in

https://www.aurigma.com/docs/us8/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing.htm

NodeJS in

[How to enable cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in the express.js framework on node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181546/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-the-express-js-framework-o)

XAMPP in

[How do I enable cross-origin resource sharing on XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872760/how-do-i-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-xampp)

Good luck ☺

Comment: Do you know how to add access-control-allow-origin with a condition of file extension. For example, only allow .jpeg/.gif/.png file to have the access-control-allow-origin

Comment: This is for Apache : [Allowing cross-origin use of images and canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#web_server_configuration)

This if for IIs : [Enabling CORS on IIS for only Font files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647732/enabling-cors-on-iis-for-only-font-files)

but you need to replace regex with this **pattern = "^[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$"**