# Using local files in bokeh.plotting

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I am using `bokeh` to display pins on a map and want when hoovering to display a JPG.
The code below works well when the image is from the internet (i.e. with a URL) but how can I make it work if the image is on the local drive, i.e. 'C:.....\pic.jpg'?

This works:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    imgs=[
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'https://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
    ]))
```

This doesn't work:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource, figure, output_file, show
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    imgs=[
        'C:\snake.jpg',
        'C:\snake2.png',
        'C:\snake3D.png',
        'C:\snake4_TheRevenge.png',
        'C:\snakebite.jpg'
    ]))
```

Comment: This is not possible, full stop.  Browsers will not allow loading local files like this into HTML Canvas, for security reasons. There's nothing we can do about that. The files will have to be properly served from a web server, even just one running on localhost.

Comment: BUt if I type on a browser: 'C:...' it will work....

Comment: If I install IIS - this can be done via 'localhost\'?

Comment: Yes as long as it is an http (or https) url. And the browser will load *a local file*. What it will *not* do is load a local file *into another existing page*.

Comment: So basically if I put the images in the 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' folder and access it e.g. http://localhost/photos/cat.jpg it should load?

Comment: You also need to confiigure the web server for cross-domain sharing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013097/unable-to-load-image-from-localhost-url-because-of-cross-origin